# Parsing String with Python

Tags: python, string-parsing

How can I parse a string `['FED590498']` in python, so than I can get all numeric values `590498` and chars `FED` separately.

Some Samples:

```
['ICIC889150']
['FED889150']
['MFL541606']
```

and [ ] is not part of string...

Comment: And what is the pattern here? Is there always 3 characters, then numbers? Is there a mix? Are the `[`, `]` brackets part of the string, are the quotes?

Comment: 3 or 4 character then numbers...

Comment: If you can give us *multiple* input samples and expected output for each we can actually help you here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the number of letters is variable, it's easiest to use a regular expression:

```
import re

characters, numbers = re.search(r'([A-Z]+)(\d+)', inputstring).groups()
```

This assumes that:

- The letters are uppercase ASCII
- There is at least 1 character, and 1 digit in each input string.

You can lock the pattern down further by using `{3, 4}` instead of `+` to limit repetition to just *3 or 4* instead of *at least 1*, etc.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputstring = 'FED590498'
>>> characters, numbers = re.search(r'([A-Z]+)(\d+)', inputstring).groups()
>>> characters
'FED'
>>> numbers
'590498'
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn Pieters

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it more idiomatic to use `re.search` in combination with `groups` or `re.findall` with `[0]`?

Comment: @Matt: I'd use `re.search()` here if it is an error for there to be more than one such pattern in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Given the requirement that there are always 3 or 4 letters you can use:

```
import re
characters, numbers = re.findall(r'([A-Z]{3,4})(\d+)', 'FED590498')[0]
characters, numbers
#('FED', '590498')
```

Or even:

```
ids = ['ICIC889150', 'FED889150', 'MFL541606']
[re.search(r'([A-Z]{3,4})(\d+)', id).groups() for id in ids]
#[('ICIC', '889150'), ('FED', '889150'), ('MFL', '541606')]
```

As suggested by Martjin, `search` is the preferred way.